# When I try to scroll down on my UIScrollview, it bounces back to the same place it was

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll, scrollview, bounce

Okay, so i'm using a UIScrollView in my app. I have placed the scrollview in a viewcontroller in story board. I have several buttons there and a few labels. But when I try to scroll down to the buttons at the bottom, the scrollview just bounces back to the top. This is the code I have used:

**In viewcontroller.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *hovscroll;
}
@end
```

**In viewcontroller.m:**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [hovscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [hovscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1500) ];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **disable paging**. There are (at least) two ways of doing this:

- In the storyboard, select the UIScrollView component, and un-tick "Paging Enabled" in the "Attributes Inspector."
- In the code, by using:

  ```
  scrollView.pagingEnabled = FALSE;
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the size of the scrollable area by setting the contentSize property of your scroll view like this.

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

Comment: I have already done that. I have just named the outlet "hovscroll".

Comment: Most probably the frame of your scroll view is not set properly. Try moving it around to a different positions and decrease it's width and height to understand where exactly are its bounds.